# C++ How to add new functionality that shares mostly the same code?

Tags: c++, oop

I currently have a class that processes files on a local file system.

```
Class FileProcessor
{
public:
   UpdateFiles();
private:
   processFiles();
   checkFileIsCorrupted();
}
```

Now, I want to add a new functionality, where the same file processing is done on files that first needed to be downloaded, but then it would call processFiles() and checkFileIsCorrupted() as before and do the same processing.

I'm wondering what's the best way to do this is.

1. I could change the interface for UpdateFiles() and add a parameter do determine whether I need to download the files, but modifying the public interface is clearly not ideal.
2. I could add a new public interface function UpdateFilesFromRemote() and thus share the private members, though this would seem to violate the single responsibility principle, which would call for the "new" functionality to be its own class.
3. Make a new class.  This would either duplicate all the code in processFiles() and processData(), or require a new base class where processFiles() and checkFileIsCorrupted() are protected members,and all the private member they call on would also need to be moved to protected in this base class as well.    However, from what I've read so far, most people seem to consider using protected to be something to avoid.
4. Make a new class and make processFiles() and checkFileIsCorrupted() friends of both classes.   I'm assuming this would require both functions to take FileProcessor and the new class as objects (or a base class interface), so that the private members can be accessed.    Although both FileProcessor  and the new class would share many private members, and so that would still require them to be protected in the base class interface.    Also, having a design where checkFileIsCorrupted() needs to take a FileProcessor object as input just... doesn't feel right.  After all, its not actually modifying the FileProcessor object, its just a helper function to check if a file is corrupted.
5. Make a new class and  make processFiles() and checkFileIsCorrupted() non member, non friend functions.   This would mean that internal file information that is private to both classes would need to be passed as function parameters to these non-member, non friend functions, breaking encapsulation.

Either way, no solutions seems to be "good".   Is there any better way to design this?
Thanks.

Comment: my opinion, you can create a FileCustomClass element inside FileProcessor. and your FileProcessor won't care about how to get file from remote or local, it only care about processing file. and FileCustomClass will responsibility for get file.

Comment: Does this class have any data? If not, consider freeing the functions from the class. (This isn't Java.) In the .cpp you can put as many helper "implementation-detail" functions in an anonymous namespace (`namespace { /* hidden "private" functions go here */ }`). Making a new function (especially a private one) should never be a big decision: It just means you have a few lines of logic that are self-contained. For more on the philosophy of small functions: this classic talk by Sean Parent of Adobe (an architect of Photoshop): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W2tWOdzgXHA

Comment: @Ben it does have data, but its not used in all the helpers.   Separating out processing the file makes sense, thanks :)